# Java Spring - How to get one specific key value from a very nested json without mapping to a specific pojo?

Tags: java, json, spring

Small java and spring question regarding how to get a specific key value from a very nested json, without having to map back to java pojos please.

I am consuming an api, where the json response is gigantic. The raw response does not fit in a screen.

The response is also very nested. Meaning, it has fields inside fields inside fields... etc

I have no access, no way to modify this API.

Nonetheless, it is a very interesting API, and in this very gigantic payload, very nested, there is **always exactly one** `"the-key-i-need": "the-value-i-need",`

Furthermore, there is no way to know in advanced how nested (which layer, which child) and no way to know where will `"the-key-i-need": "the-value-i-need",` be.

Also, there is no way to map the response back to any POJO, it changes always, the only information, `"the-key-i-need": "the-value-i-need",` exists, and it is always there.

I am well aware of GSON or fasterxml libraries, that can help map the json string back to existing pojos.

However, in my case, such will not help, since the existing pojo does not exists. the response is always different, the structure, the level of nesting is always different.

My question is, instead of trying to map back to pojos that will always change, and very nested, is there a simpler way, to just use some kind of regex, or something else, to extract the key value, `"the-key-i-need": "the-value-i-need",` and only this please?

I already tried mapping to all kinds of pojos, and unfortunately the response structure is too dynamic.

Thank you

Comment: I mean you can just mostly ignore that the file is in JSON format if you just need one attribute from a gigantic structure. Just use a reader to go through each line and stop when you found the expected key value pair.

Comment: What you want to look for is "java json dom", which loads a JSON into an in-memory dynamic structure (a Document Object Model or DOM) that you can then query.  There are several packages out there, but recommendations are off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: @magicmn You're assuming that the JSON is formatted for human consumption, with one property per line, and nicely indented. That is unlikely to be the case.

Comment: @Andreas Even if it isn't, just going through the file and looking for the word `the-key-i-need` and then reading the following value is the easiest way to solve this. He said that `the-key-i-need` is unique in the entire DOM, so duplicates shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: So, yes, the json response from the API is not human readable, it is more of a one line gigantic payload @ Andreas @ magicmn

Comment: Seems like you looking for [gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Comment: I am having a hard time using GSON, fasterxml, or other libraries, since there is no object to map it back to in my case @VictorGubin

Comment: Besides having to loop through the entire response, and parse the key value, can I just extract it with some kind of regex or something similar? Not Sur if it is possible, or how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Spring, you very likely already have [Jackson FasterXML](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson#jackson-project-home-github) in you classpath.

Normally, Spring uses the [Databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) module, which relies on the [Streaming](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core) module, aka the Core module.

In this case, you want to use Streaming directly, so get the JSON text as a `String`, and start the parser.

```java
static String getFieldValue(String json, String field) throws JsonParseException, IOException {
    JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
    try (JsonParser parser = factory.createParser(json)) {
        for (JsonToken token; (token = parser.nextToken()) != null; ) {
            if (token == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME && parser.getCurrentName().equals(field)) {
                token = parser.nextToken();
                // check token here if object or array should throw exception instead of returning null
                return parser.getValueAsString();
            }
        }
    }
    return null; // or throw exception if "not found" shouldn't return null
}
```

*Test*

```java
String json = "{ \"A\": { \"B\": [ 5, { \"C\": \"D\" }, true ], \"E\": null, \"F\": 42, \"G\": false }}";
System.out.println("C: " + getFieldValue(json, "C")); // "D"
System.out.println("E: " + getFieldValue(json, "E")); // null (null-value)
System.out.println("F: " + getFieldValue(json, "F")); // "42"
System.out.println("G: " + getFieldValue(json, "G")); // "false"
System.out.println("H: " + getFieldValue(json, "H")); // null (not found)
System.out.println("B: " + getFieldValue(json, "B")); // null (not a value)
```

Comment: many thanks @Andreas for the answer, snippet and test case

Answer (score 1):

### JsonPath

If using an external library is an option, then [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) might help.

#### Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

[StackOverflow Tag for JsonPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonpath)

Example usage as shared in the [README](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#path-examples)

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century"
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

To access all the author names

```java
    List<String> authors = JsonPath.read(json, "$..author");
    System.out.println(authors);
```

Output

```
["Nigel Rees","Evelyn Waugh"]
```

To access all the prices (across both book and bicycle)

```java
    List<Double> prices = JsonPath.read(json, "$..price");
    System.out.println(prices);
```

Output

```
[12.99, 19.95]
```

### Note

Some missing keys can cause remapping extracted data across two fields difficult

Say fetching category and price from the above example will make it difficult to summarize a category to price mapping

```java
  List<String> categories = JsonPath.read(json, "$..category");
  System.out.println(categories);
```

Output

```
["reference", "fiction"]
```

Based on the above example, `price` and `category` does not have correct 1-1 mapping

Comment: To be an answer, it should show more, e.g. example of use. As-is, this is more of a comment.